# Use wild card in mock service URL

Tags: rest, groovy, mocking, soapui

I need to mock a rest service, the mock is already working on SoapUI. The problem is that I have created a mock with a URL like this `/test/userA/`.

Is there a way to create a mock that would also respond to a url `/test/userB/`? I was thinking something like `/test/user?/` or `test/user[A-Z]/`. Is it possible with SoapUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit late, but here it is a possible solution...

There is no way to configure this kind of path in SOAPUI mockService, however you can emulate your goal using the follow approach:

You can configure as url path only `/` this way all request to `http://your.mock.host:port/` will be processed in mockService.

Then to check if the path is what you want `/test/user[A-Z]/` and to respond differently based on the [A-Z] you can use the follow groovy script in for example `onRequest script` tab of your mockService or alternatively in `Dispatch(SCRIPT)` tab of your operation inside mockService:

```
// the regex
def pathRegex = /^\/test\/user([A-Z])\//  

// get the request path
def path = mockRequest.getPath()

// check if the path is correct
def matcher = (path =~ pathRegex)  

// path is not correct 
// change assert to do your logic break... 
assert matcher.matches()

// path is correct get the exaclty user[A-Z] to do 
// your logic
def letter = matcher.group(1)
log.info letter
// do your logic depends on letter
...
```

This scripts behaves like:

For URL `/wrong/url/`

Output:

```
assert matcher.matches()
           |       |
           |       false
           java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=^/test/test([A-Z])/ region=0,10 lastmatch=]
```

For URL `/test/userA/`

`Wed Nov 04 10:02:06 CET 2015:INFO:A`

For URL `/test/userW/`

`Wed Nov 04 10:02:33 CET 2015:INFO:W`

Hope this helps,